# parsing json with json.net and handling nullexception on jobject

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am using json.net to parse json and after converting the string into an object like this

```
 Dim jobj As JObject = JObject.Parse(tweet)
 sid = jobj("id").ToString
```

It seems to work fine but I get the nullexception when a specific tag does not exist. How can I handle this? 
For example if in the following:

```
"id":123456787,
"id_str":"123456787",
"text":"HELLO help with parsing json",
```

If the id_str field was not there it would throw an error and I don't want to check for nulls on each field I am trying to parse. Another was I tried was to the jobj and get a list of all the children and then iterating through them.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [direct cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) with the `CType` operator to cast from a  [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) that has a string value directly to a string:

```
Dim jobj As JObject = JObject.Parse(tweet)
Dim sid = CType(jobj("id"), String)
```

This works because `JToken` has a large number of [explicit type conversions](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Operators_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) to primitive data types built in.  And, when the primitive type is a reference type or nullable, the explicit cast operators will return `Nothing` on a null input.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OY97vu).

You could also use the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) in Visual Studio 2015.